# Use of undeclared identifier for a macro

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, macros

In my app i'm performing following steps

1) Created a .h file Say, GlobalMacros.h

In GlobalMacros.h

```
#define IP_ADDR @“SERVER_IP”
```

2) In my apps .pch file

```
import “GlobalMacros.h”
```

Then in rest of the other classes i'm using this IP_ADDR macro in iOS<5.0 no Problems but in iOS>5.0 i'm getting an error **use of undeclared identifier IP_ADDR**

Comment: Write this line #define IP_ADDR @“SERVER_IP” in .pch file. then it will work fine

Comment: Do you use the `“` and `”` quotes in your source code, or did you type up your question in an editor that autocorrects normal quotes into the opposing ones?

Comment: Namespace your stuff. GlobalMacros.h is a terrible name. Likely already used elsewhere. IP_ADDR is also stupidly generic. Seriously. You should be using a completely different technique for string constants. Like actual string constants. WTF

Answer (score 3):

The reason is one of these:

- the `.pch file` has some `#if` test that conditionally includes `#import "GlobalMacros.h"` if the build version is less than iOS5
- the `GlobalMacros.h` file has the conditional `#if` in it
- some header or source file has a `#if` statement in it that undefines `IP_ADDR`
- in the project that is less than iOS5, the `.pch` file is using a different `GlobalMacros.h` file, not the one that has the `IP_ADDR` define in it

EDIT: I should add that in `Xcode4.5`, I have this global macros file included in my `.pch` file. For some reason, the preprocessor gets confused, and the source code editor is showing unknown macros in many files, seemingly at random. What I am doing is as I get errors, adding the global macros file to the affected file.

Comment: I defined my macro inside the `.m` file. This solved my problem

Comment: @亚历山大 if you need to use that MACRO in other files, putting it in each is a terrible solution. In that case you should put it in the .pch file, or a global.h file that is included where the macros are needed.

Comment: Why not namespace your stuff. GlobalMacros is a terrible solution for a header file name.

Comment: Normally you're right, but its just about a single var I used inside my `AppDelegate.m` otherwise I use `enums` or define them only in one place, normally also inside `.pch`